# PokeAPI's sprites are not getting loaded

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, pokeapi

When I try to load the sprites of various Pokemons using PokeAPI in python, nothing shows up.

**Note**: It was working when I last tested my application a few months ago.

The link which I try to load(in my kivyMD application through AsyncImage widget):

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/{id of the Pokemon}.png
```

I have also tried loading it using the requests module using the get function (just to check whether the problem is with the library or with the API), but I got the same results :(

Can someone please help me out? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Have u tried [https://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites/tree/ca5a7886c10753144e6fae3b69d45a4d42a449b4/sprites/pokemon](https://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites/tree/ca5a7886c10753144e6fae3b69d45a4d42a449b4/sprites/pokemon)

Comment: Yes, I have tried :(

Comment: Have just posted an answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct way to get the images is:

```py
import requests

url = "https://github.com/PokeAPI/sprites/blob/ca5a7886c10753144e6fae3b69d45a4d42a449b4/sprites/pokemon/{id}.png?raw=true"
pokemon_id = "1"

response = requests.get(url.format(id=pokemon_id))

# Save the image
with open("pokemon.png", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

What saves an image of "Bulbasaur" in png format. Hope it helps!